# How to export SQL script file into Excel column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a SQL script file suppose `student.sql` (placed somewhere) like:

```
update student set sname='xyz' where RollID='101';

update student set sname='axz' where RollID='102';
```

I want to export value of `sname` and `RollID` into on Excel on column wise for each rows.

How to export the column values. Kindly help, I will highly solicited to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can try "Find" to locate the position, and "MID" to cut text.

e.g. (assuming a sql  update student set sname='xyz' where RollID='101';  is put in cell A1)

=FIND("sname=",A1,1)+7 - means the begining position of xyz (7 means length of sname='), assuming this formula is put in B1

=FIND("' where Roll", A1) - means the ending position of xyz, assuming this formula is put in C1

then, the below formula give you xyz
=MID(A1, B1,C1-B1)

Comment: This would be easier to read if the SQL were formatted as code.  Please see 'Help' at the top right of the answer window for how to do this.